# How to resolve OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files when performing POST calls with three different URLs using aiohttp?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have csv file from which one column serves as the data that is passed in two of the POST method calls. I have three different URLs which need to be called subsequently in the code. I define the session using aiohttp and loop for the column length(one whose cell values are sent in two of the POST calls). The data obtained from the responses is stored in a list and that is used for a third POST call with different url.

The first two calls seem to execute fine and pretty fast(i printed the responses for them and verified), but when execution comes to the third one, this error shows up:

> OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

I have tried some solutions which suggest to specify `connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)` in `aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False))`
But this doesn't work. What should be the best way to tackle this? The second URL curently that i use is an HTTP one, localhost url, which will be changed to https cloud based url eventually.

Here is the example code depicting the situation:

```
import aiohttp
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import requests
import json
import time

start_time = time.time()

df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv', header=None, dtype=str)
RequestBodyvalues = df.iloc[:, [0]].values

async def get_FirstUrlresponse(session, url, requestBody, headers):
    async with session.post(url, data = json.dumps(requestBody), headers = headers) as resp:
        response = await resp.json()
        return response

async def get_SecondUrlresponse(session, url, requestBody, headers):
    async with session.post(url, data = json.dumps(requestBody), headers = headers) as resp:
        response = await resp.json()
        return response

async def get_ThirdUrlresponse(session, url, requestBody, headers):
    async with session.post(url, data = json.dumps(requestBody), headers = headers) as resp:
        response = await resp.json()
        return response

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        FirstUrlTasks = []
        SecondUrlTasks = []
        for reqBody in RequestBodyvalues:
            firstUrl = 'https://firstUrl.com/searchByValue'
            secondUrl = 'http://secondUrl.com/someEndpoint'
            requestBody = {'value': reqBody}
            headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer Token', 
            'content-type': 'application/json'}

            FirstUrlTasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_FirstUrlresponse(session, firstUrl, requestBody, headers)))
            SecondUrlTasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_SecondUrlresponse(session, secondUrl, requestBody, headers)))
        
        firstUrlResponses = await asyncio.gather(*FirstUrlTasks)
        secondUrlresponses = await asyncio.gather(*SecondUrlTasks)

        valuesForThridUrl = []
        for secondUrlresponse in secondUrlresponses:
            #Logic to fetch values to pass to Third Url stored in list

        ThirdUrlTasks = []
        for value in valuesForThridUrl:
            ThirdUrl = 'https://thirdUrl.com/someEndpoint'
            requestBody = {'reqBody': value}
            headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer Token', 
            'content-type': 'application/json'}

            ThirdUrlTasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_ThirdUrlresponse(session, ThirdUrl, requestBody, headers)))

        thirdUrlresponses = await asyncio.gather(*ThirdUrlTasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See open file limits with this command

```
ulimit -n
```

and then increase limit

```
ulimit -n NUM
```

Comment: Great, it works! Could you elaborate a bit what this does and what should be the minimum or maximum limit, just for learning. Anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: But even though it executes, the responses for third url after 300 or so are like Rate Limit has exceeded(Try Again in 30 seconds), can this also be solved by some tweak, or is it because of the rate limit in Cosmos DB where the query is eventually made by the endpoint?

Comment: Ulimit is the number of open file descriptors per process. It is a method for restricting the number of various resources a process can consume. I didn't see any suggestion on what min and max are good for this value. It's based on your application need.

Comment: This error depends on the rate of open processes your application use. Maybe decreasing simultaneous process help that. Or you should set a bigger ulimit value.

Comment: Yes i understood that is because of more simultaneous process per second. I tried increasing the ulimit to higher value, which didnt solve the issue. How should i use asyncio.sleep in this code to decrease the simultaneous requests or retry them?

Comment: I think maybe your `valuesForThridUrl` length is huge. You should divide the list and run every part on a single thread, not running every value of the list with a different thread.